# How to grep and exclude "nn/nn" matches

Tags: grep, containers, kubectl

I have the following example data (from the output of 'command'):

```
field1   field2   1/1   field4
field1   field2   2/2   field4
field1   field2   10/10   field4
field1   field2   5/7   field4
```

I'd like to only display the lines where the first number does not match the second number in field3.

I have this grep command which works fine when the numbers are a single digits:

```
command | grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+'
```

So when I use the grep above with the example data, I get the following displayed:

```
field1   field2   10/10   field4
field1   field2   5/7   field4
```

Ideally I want the line with 10/10 also matched and excluded.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** This could be done with a simple `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting up field separator as space(s) OR `/` for all the lines. In main program checking if 3rd field is equal to 4th field then print that line.

```
your_command | awk -F'[[:space:]]+|/' '$3!=$4'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
your_command | awk '{split($3,arr,"/");if(arr[1]!=arr[2]){print}}'
```

Comment: the only minor problem with this approach is, that the input is different when `kubectl get pod -n <namespace>` is run vs `kubectl get pod -A`, the field of the READY state change from 3rd to 2nd.  However, if the user is ensuring the sanity of input, then it's not an issue.!

Comment: Excellent, thank you, the awk option worked well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below command:

```
kubectl get pod |grep -P '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
```

the command provided in the question was failing the edge case due to the handling of completed pods. Which is updated here.

**Example:**

```
kubectl get pod
NAME   READY  STATUS     RESTARTS  AGE
app_1   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_2   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_3   0/1    Completed  0         77m
app_4   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_5   8/8    Running    0         77m
app_6   4/4    Running    1         77m
app_7   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_8   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_9   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_10  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_11  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_12  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_13  1/1    Running    0         75m
app_14  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_15  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_16  2/2    Running    0         76m
app_17  4/8    Running    0         77m
app_18  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_19  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_20  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_21  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_22  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_23  3/3    Running    0         77m
app_24  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_25  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_26  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_27  10/10  Running    0         77m
app_28  2/2    Running    0         77m
```

**Ready pods:**

```
kubectl get pod |grep -P '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
app_1   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_2   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_4   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_5   8/8    Running    0         77m
app_6   4/4    Running    1         77m
app_7   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_8   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_9   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_10  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_11  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_12  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_13  1/1    Running    0         75m
app_14  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_15  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_16  2/2    Running    0         76m
app_18  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_19  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_20  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_21  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_22  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_23  3/3    Running    0         77m
app_24  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_25  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_26  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_27  10/10  Running    0         77m
app_28  2/2    Running    0         77m
```

**Not Ready pods:**

```
kubectl get pod|grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
NAME   READY  STATUS     RESTARTS  AGE
app_3   0/1    Completed  0         77m
app_17  4/8    Running    0         77m
```